# I looked at the mirror and saw: "me" or "myself"?

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

Which one is right to use in the following sentence?

> I looked at the mirror and saw *Me / Myself*.

Comment: Most common and idiomatic is *myself*. But *me* can be used to express a more intense recognition, carrying an element of surprise. Usually it's used in contexts of self-recognition, such as "seeing myself *as I truly am*", perhaps for the first time (or perhaps because you switched bodies with a talking kangaroo  for two weeks and this morning when you woke up and glimpsed yourself in the mirror, you saw that you were back in your old, familiar, comfortable body, thank god).

Answer (score 3):

At Google Books

"I saw myself in the mirror"
About 16,500 results

is quite common, while

"I saw me in the mirror"
5 results

is rare. It sounds **uneducated and dialectal**.

The first is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "myself". (I would probably also say "looked in the mirror" rather than "looked at the mirror".)